# pyqt5 rtsp stream delay

Tags: pyqt5, rtsp

I was trying to make GUI with pyqt5 which streams the video from rtsp link of a IP camera which is connected with my pc through ethernet cable. The average delay of the video feed is 300ms. Is there any way to reduce the delay?

I am using qt multimedia and a windows 11 OS.